# Mootools: How to create new element `span` inside `li` element on mouseove?

Tags: javascript, list, mootools, element, mouseover

The HTML code:

```
<ul id="el">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

*How to create new element `span` inside `li` element on mouseover?*

```
<ul id="el">
   <li></li>
   <li></li>
   <li><span></span></li><!--on mouseover > new element span-->
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this:

```
document.getElements('#el > li').addEvent('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var target = document.id(e.target);
  if (!target.getElement('span')) target.adopt(new Element('span'));
});
```

if you want to remove the span on mouse out, then add this:

```
document.getElements('#el > li').addEvent('mouseleave', function(e) {
  document.id(e.target).getElements('span').destroy();
});
```

be careful as these are very naive implementations and are the bare minimum you need for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('el').addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
  var e=e.target;
  if (e.nodeName=="LI") {
    var span=e.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
    if(!span) {
      e.innerHTML="<span></span>";
    }
  }
},false);
```

This will do a check for an existing `SPAN` before inserting it. In addition it does not require JQuery or any other JS framework.

Tested on Firefox, but some browsers *might* handle the `e.target` part differently so just bear that in mind.

Comment: No. My example DOES work. I tested it in Safari 5.0.1, Firefox 3.6.8, and Chrome 5.0.375.

See this link for Javascript with HTML: http://ifelse.org/projects/stackoverflow/3417148.html

 If you cannot get it to work I would appreciate the courtesy of detailing how you implemented it so I can verify.

Comment: Glad to hear it. The original code posted wouldn't show any visual change (you'd have to use Firebug etc to see it) since I worked with the sample HTML you gave me. Was that the problem? Out of curiosity, if it had 'worked' for you, would I have been give the 'best answer'? :)

Comment: I asked for Mootools solution not usual JS. Thanks for your post anyway!

Comment: You're welcome. Minor point: while you tagged it mootools, you didn't clarify it MooTools until after I posted. Also, I don't see why it should be mootool specific when normal JS works as it. Swapping 'document.getElementById' etc with $ isn't a huge deal. All the best